# Why is personnel management decision-making so different to that in other functions?

Tags: management, human-resources

I don't want to sound cynical and I am sure that selfish decision criteria exist in other functions than HR. Yet I do find that, in general, personnel selection decisions tend to be quite different in their priorities than decisions in finance, engineering, marketing, production, design, etc.

In the other functions, alternatives are weighed for the benefits and risks attached to each option before a final decision is made.

But in HR - as especially in personnel selection - no manager seems to worry too much about a new appointee being poor, i.e. demonstrably adequate in the appearance-related aspects of the job but not much use in tackling the tasks of his/her function nor in raising the standard of that division of the company. (A Type I error)

Neither do personnel managers really care about having *not* selected candidates for a job who later on achieved great things in rival organizations. (The Type II error)

Yet all personnel managers seem hyper-vigilant about the possibility that a candidate being short-listed for interview not have anything on their CV that might on later review be seen as something that would invalidate their candidacy - and cast doubt on the judgement of the personnel manager involved.

The result of the latter focus is that larger organizations tend to hire personnel in a very defensive way. While this minimizes the risk of hiring truly hopeless staff, it also ensures - through the effect of the resulting human environment on good capable candidates as well as by direct appointment of pedestrian ones - that the organization's creativity and efficiency are limited by the HR function. Which is the exact opposite to what the HR function is supposed to do: to search for, evaluate and select the best possible staff for the current vacant positions in their organizations.

It really does seem that not only do HR managers take a defensive approach to hiring new staff but they also take a very defensive approach to advancing in their own career. They seem to think that promotion through *not having done* X (unlike a colleague, Mr Z) is a more reliable path that through *having done* Y.

Can any HR insiders please help me with this most cloying question ?

Comment: You made  A LOT of assertions and assumption about the hiring process. Most of these are IMO wrong or not typical. For starters hiring decisions are almost always made by the hiring manger, not HR. Since the hiring manager needs to live with the consequences of the decision, most are quite careful and deliberate with that decision.

Comment: I haven't worked at any company where HR made hiring decisions for anyone outside of HR.  They should be a resource that you use at various stages  of the interviewing/hiring process, not drivers of the process.

Comment: @Hilmar  and cdkMoose    Are you saying that HR had no veto on the chosen candidate's manager's choice (or whoever in the function spoke for it) ? If so, it simply adds to my point that the HR manager simply acted as a jobsworth administrator in the process and did not assert their right as a responsible party to exert some control over the final selection.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere  In over 30 years I have seen little difference in the attitude of HR managers. The odd exception was more a case of an individual following their own (in truth a correct) interpretation of their job. Most of these got frozen out by their organizations due to not going along with the org line.

Comment: I am downvoting this question because it seems like the poster is venting more than asking a serious question. FWIW I do empathize.

Comment: @John Wu  How can you claim to empathize with the question yet add more weight to the very viewpoint I am questioning? Did we get any answers from the commenters?

Comment: Voting to close because this just seems like a rant.

Answer (score 2):

I think you attribute to much weight to HR in the hiring practice. They usually don't have a great deal of say when it comes to skilled staff.

> While this minimizes the risk of hiring truly hopeless staff

This should be the main filter, the vast majority of jobs do not require highly strung geniuses, they're best served by cleancut people who just do the work quietly.

Comment: At least you are not claiming HR concern for type I and type II hiring errors like Mr Strazzere. But: (1) Do HR managers even have a veto in respect of disturbing indicators in the hiring manager's choice candidate ? If not, then **what** - administration and statutory requirements apart - does the HR manager actually do ? and (2) If a HR senior manager is a director of the organization, how does he/she justify their director status without accepting responsibility for hiring errors ?

Comment: It differs from company to company and locale to locale. But anywhere you would find it rare for directors to take the blame for anything.

Comment: @Trunk, the purpose of HR is to protect the company from mistakes in following government regulations and when dealing with employees. It is primarily a "defensive" role. As such, "middle of the road" is far safer than taking any chances. Based on this requirement, your "hiring errors" are not errors in fact. In many countries, HR has to deal with a multitude of government regulations which could shut the company down which is why HR has such a high profile.

Comment: @David R  Are you sure that this role of protecting against failure to follow all (not just employee) government regulations isn't just a red herring that gives HR managers a pretext to avoid more creative/constructive work in their essential function ? The additional work you refer to seems to me to be more like stuff for the legal department or the company's lawyers. But let us say that a given company decrees that this work *is* to be done within the HR division and represented on the board by the HR director. In that case the HR director just allocates some qualified staff to the task.

Comment: HR is not supposed to be creative, they're supposed to follow procedures carefully and completely.

Comment: @Trunk, I've run a business for over 30 years. I have to fill out a number of government forms each year for me as an employee. When I have more employees, the forms multiply, and the regulations get worse. I just worked on a system to track and report to the government health insurance coverage for employees. In other countries, the regulations and reporting requirements can be worse. You don't see all this. HR's job is not to find new employees; that is the "red herring" to take their attention from their essential function.

Comment: @Kilisi  But procedures into which the HR function ought to have major input.

Comment: @David R  You seem to be defining the HR Director job to suit yourself in that you assign greater importance to legal/admin functions. This might be more rationally assigned to a separate bureau (e.g. "Admin") that report directly to the CEO/MD. Incidentally, I think that stopping people defining the limits of their own jobs is one of the main tasks of proper personnel management. As is stopping the hiring manager appointing someone with doubtful skills/experience/character/energy. Yet maybe HR is a division of an organization (like Design) where the true potential of the position is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the next two statements:

> 1. Company X hired a person smarter than Albert Eistein.

and

> 2. Company X hired a person so *(you choose how)* that he literally obliterated half a continent in the first three hours of his employment. The person hired earlier, smarter than Einstein, was unfortunately obliterated in the process, too.

Which will be the thing that people will remember "forever"? That they found some genius person? I am quite sure that company X will be a rich source of memes and jokes for months or years to come. They will be identified with that disaster harbinger for a very long time.

That is why the first step in hiring people is to "make sure" that the applicant will not bring doom on the future of the company. It is not only the task of HR to filter out these people, but the job of "everybody".

---

About the other statements in your question: while they are true in a number of situations, they should not be generalized. There are countless brilliant employees employed by countless wonderful managers and by countless inspired HR's in the world to prove the opposite. Unfortunately, the latter cannot be generalized either :(

Comment: Surely there is a "happy mean" position somewhere between not hiring hopeless staff and (probationally) hiring staff that need a bit of training in certain areas of their job before the company can enjoy the full measure of their other talents. I really think there ought to be more focus on developing talent rather than simply exploiting existing skills acquired/learned elsewhere.

Comment: *"I really think there ought to be more focus on developing talent rather than simply exploiting existing skills acquired/learned elsewhere."* - I could not agree more.